# SET VALUE to INPUT type Text with FUNCTION HTML

Tags: html, input, tags

this is part of my code :

```
<script>
        function setCard() {
            var carta = document.getElementById('idlistaCarte').value;
            document.getElementById('idcodice_carta').innerHTML = carta;

        }
</script>

<table>

    <tr>
        <td><p>Conferma Pagamento</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select name="listaCarte" id="idlistaCarte">
                <%
                    int i = 0;
                    for (String titolareCarta : listatitolare_carta) {
                %>
                <option value="<%=listacodice_carta.get(i)%>"
                    id="idcodice_carta_select">
                    <%=titolareCarta%>,<%=listacodice_carta.get(i)%>,<%=listatipologia_carta.get(i)%>
                </option>
                <%
                    i++;
                    }
                %>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="setCard()" value="Set Card"></td>
        <td><p id="idcodice_carta"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="codice_carta"
            name="codice_carta" id="idcodice_carta" required></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to pass the value in the input type text with id = "idcodice_carta" taking the value from the select via button.
I can not make it.
trying to populate a p tag this works, but I need to have the value in the input field.
How can I solve the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change id either

```
<td><p id="idcodice_carta"></p></td>
```

or

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="codice_carta"
                name="codice_carta" id="idcodice_carta" required>
```

you can't use same id in one page  ex  "idcodice_carta"

Comment: I put this <td><p id="idcodice_carta"></p></td> only as an example, to say that this works but if I replace it with this other   <input type="text" placeholder="codice_carta"
                name="codice_carta" id="idcodice_carta" required> no